# The value passing through Intent returns null some time

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing some values through Intent, in some case the value passed through it returns null. The value is not null till it sets on the intent. Here is the code where I am setting intent.

```
Intent propertyIntent = new Intent(mContext , SomeActivity.class);
propertyIntent.putExtra(START_MODE_TAG,MODE_EDIT_RECORDING);
propertyIntent.putExtra(ACTIVITY_MODE_TAG, "dm");
propertyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
propertyIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("det_list", detList);
mContext.startActivity(propertyIntent);
```

Here is the code which is used to fetch the intent values

```
passedModeName = getIntent().getStringExtra(DMApplication.START_MODE_TAG);
```

only `START_MODE_TAG` value returns null rest all returns correctly. I tried setting in `onNewIntent()` also. But no use.

Constants which I used in it

```
public static final String ACTIVITY_MODE_TAG="activity_mode";
public static final String START_MODE_TAG="StartMode";
public static final String MODE_NEW_RECORDING="new";
public static final String MODE_EDIT_RECORDING="edit";
public static final String MODE_REVIEW_RECORDING="review";
public static final String MODE_COPY_RECORDING="copy";
public static final String MODE_LAUNCH_RECORDING="launch";
```

Comment: Then `MODE_EDIT_RECORDING` must be null.

Comment: Can you post your constant definitions too, please?

Comment: not sure why it would make a difference (it has for me) but try qualifying all of the key Strings eg `START_MODE_TAG="com.my.package.StartMode"`

Answer (score 0):

You should get the extras data in the following way.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
selectedGroupId = extras.getString(DMApplication.START_MODE_TAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the keys *DMApplication.START_MODE_TAG* is same as *START_MODE_TAG* and MODE_EDIT_RECORDING is not null.

Comment: I checked it, it is having value till I set these on Intent.